# Jenkins Git hook

Tags: git, jenkins, hook, gitblit

I have setup a Jenkins CI (standalone port 8081) git over Ubuntu apt-get and gitblit runs on a Tomcat 7.

On my Server the Git home is not more owned by the git user, it's own by tomcat7 that I can create new Repos with gitblit.

Ich can also push and pull commits. But I can't start the Jenkins build after a commit.

In the 'hooks' directory from the repository I have add a new File called post-receive.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://myserver.de:8081/job/mytestrepo/build?token=aasdfbabfabfibafhbhf
```

The curl command works if I run it on the shell. But it's not run if git should start it? I don't know what I made wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitblit does not support executing native hooks; it supports hooks written in Groovy.  Gitblit comes bundled with a Jenkins Groovy hook that you can use to trigger your build.

https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/distrib/data/groovy/jenkins.groovy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be certain that commands in a shell script execute correctly, you need to give the full path.   In bash you can ask this with "type curl".  For OS X the script should read (untested)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/curl http://myserver.de:8081/job/mytestrepo/build?token=aasdfbabfabfibafhbhf
```

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, thanks but it doesn't work. the 'type curl' command gives /usr/bin/curl back. But after an push the Jenkins will not start the build.

Comment: What does the jenkins log reveal?